# Facebook login not enterting data into mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, facebook

I'm learning how to use the login with Facebook with the help of tutorials, got most running, but the data isn't being entered to the database.

Here's code got working so far

```
<?php
require 'lib/db.php';
require 'lib/facebook.php';
require 'lib/fbconfig.php';
session_start();
$facebook=$_SESSION['facebook'];
$userdata=$_SESSION['userdata'];
$logoutUrl=$_SESSION['logout'];
$access_token_title='fb_'.$facebook_appid.'_access_token';
$access_token=$facebook[$access_token_title];


if(!empty($userdata))
{
echo '<h1>Login User Details</h1>';
echo '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/'.$userdata['id'].'/picture">';
echo "<br/>";
echo '<b>Access Token: </b>'.$access_token;
echo "<br/>";
echo '<b>User ID: </b>'.$userdata['id'];
echo "<br/>";
echo  '<b>Name: </b>'.$userdata['name'];
echo "<br/>";
echo  '<b>First Name: </b>'.$userdata['first_name'];
echo "<br/>";
echo  '<b>Last Name: </b>'.$userdata['last_name'];
echo "<br/>";
echo  '<b>Email: </b>'.$userdata['email'];
echo "<br/>";
echo  '<b>Gender: </b>'.$userdata['gender'];
echo "<br/>";
echo  '<b>Birthday: </b>'.$userdata['birthday'];
echo "<br/>";
echo  '<b>Location: </b>'.$userdata['location']['name'];
echo "<br/>";
echo  '<b>Hometown: </b>'.$userdata['hometown']['name'];
echo "<br/>";
echo  '<b>Bio :</b>'.$userdata['bio'];
echo "<br/>";
echo  '<b>Relationship Status: </b>'.$userdata['relationship_status'];
echo "<br/>";
echo  '<b>Time Zone: </b>'.$userdata['timezone'];
echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>";

$facebook_id=$userdata['id'];
$name=$userdata['name'];
$email=$userdata['email'];
$gender=$userdata['gender'];
$birthday=$userdata['birthday'];
$location=mysql_real_escape_string($userdata['location']['name']);
$hometown=mysql_real_escape_string($userdata['hometown']['name']);
$bio=mysql_real_escape_string($userdata['bio']);
$relationship=$userdata['relationship_status'];
$timezone=$userdata['timezone'];
echo "$add = mysql_query('insert INSERT INTO users(`facebook_id`, `name`, `email`, `gender`, `birthday`, `location`, `hometown`, `bio`, `relationship`, `timezone`, `access_token`) 
VALUES ('$facebook_id','$name','$email','$gender','$birthday','$location','$hometown','$bio','$relationship','$timezone','$access_token')</span>";

echo "<br/>";

 echo '<a href="'.$logoutUrl.'">Logout Facebook</a>';
 }
 else
 {
  header("Location: fblogin.php");
 }
 ?>
```

Obviously doing something wrong. So does anyone know any tutorials that would help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: `Obviously doing something wrong` Yes, yes you are. Using `mysql_*` is wrong. And `echo`ing the query execution line (`$add=....`) is also wrong. Oh, and not to forget, the query that you're not executing is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You don't insert anything.

Just do:

```
$add = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(`facebook_id`, `name`, `email`, `gender`, `birthday`, `location`, `hometown`, `bio`, `relationship`, `timezone`, `access_token`) 
VALUES ('$facebook_id','$name','$email','$gender','$birthday','$location','$hometown','$bio','$relationship','$timezone','$access_token')");
```

Without that `echo`.

As a side note, I see you are still using `mysql_*` functions, If you just started you could move to `PDO` as `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. [Here is a nice tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Here is how you can accomplish this using PDO:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=UTF-8', 'username', 'password', array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(`facebook_id`, `name`, `email`, `gender`, `birthday`, `location`, `hometown`, `bio`, `relationship`, `timezone`, `access_token`) 
    VALUES (:facebook_id,:name,:email,:gender,:birthday,:location,:hometown,:bio,:relationship,:timezone,:access_token)");
$stmt->execute(array(':facebook_id' => $facebook_id, ':name' => $name, ':email' => $email, ':gender' => $gender, ':birthday' => $birthday, ':location' => $location, ':hometown' => $hometown, ':bio' => $bio, ':relationship' => $relationship, ':timezone' => $timezone, ':access_token' => $access_token));
```

Comment: "But PDO just looks soooooooooo much harder than `mysql_*`" < what most people will be thinking when they see the two together, one on top of the other. xD

Comment: I don't know how you see it harder, I like it :). With PDO you can skip all those unwanted variables.

Comment: Yeah I know. I'm perfectly fine with it. But for most newbies, that quote will be floating in their heads.

Answer (score 0):

error in your query

```
echo "$add = mysql_query('insert INSERT INTO users(`facebook_id`, `name`, `email`, `gender`, `birthday`, `location`, `hometown`, `bio`, `relationship`, `timezone`, `access_token`) VALUES ('$facebook_id','$name','$email','$gender','$birthday','$location','$hometown','$bio','$relationship','$timezone','$access_token')</span>";
```

should be

```
$add = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(`facebook_id`, `name`, `email`, `gender`, `birthday`, `location`, `hometown`, `bio`, `relationship`, `timezone`, `access_token`) VALUES ('$facebook_id','$name','$email','$gender','$birthday','$location','$hometown','$bio','$relationship','$timezone','$access_token')");
```

and try to use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead of `mysql`.